# Qt Creator Mac OS X 10.8.3 debugging helpers not working

Tags: macos, qt, gdb, qt-creator, macports

Even though the log in Qt Creator 2.7.0 for building the debugging helpers for Qt 4.8.4 shows success, and "Use Debugging Helper" is checked under Preferences > Debugger > Locals & Expressions, I still cannot inspect values such as `QString`s correctly when debugging. No errors show in the console window for the application being debugged. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with QtC2.7.0 (and also 2.6) with self-built Qt4.8.4 on the most recent OSX: did the following by build the debugger-helpers by myself.

```
copy this to the head of the dumper.pro

macx:QMAKE_CC = gcc
macx:QMAKE_CXX = g++
macx:QMAKE_LINK = g++

run the following commands

 2761  cd "/Users/Shared/current_qt/qtc-debugging-helper/" 
 2766  /Users/Shared/current_qt/bin/qmake -spec macx-g++42 dumper.pro -nocache CONFIG+=x86_64
 2767  make all -k
```